# ForEach in Laravel Command is not Executed

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am still in the process of learning Laravel and I'm currently working on a command. Basically, whenever I run my command it runs everything correctly with the exception of anything inside of the foreach statement.

My code for my command's fire function:

```
public function fire()
{
    $members = Member::where('expire', '=', Carbon::now()->today());

    $this->info('We found ' . $members->count() . ' expiring today!');

    foreach ($members as $member) {
        $this->comment('ForEach');
        $member->active = "0";
        $member->save();
        $this->comment($member->first_name . ' has been updated.');
    }

    $this->comment('Comment2');
    $this->comment('Comment3');

}
```

As I currently have no clue what I am doing wrong, I will gladly accept any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `->get()` `$members`. You're currently trying to iterate over a query builder rather than that query's results.

```
foreach ($members->get() as $member) {
```